# Radio Button with PHP

Tags: php, html, radio-button, fetch

I wanted to know why I am not able to fetch the value of radio button into the PHP Variable. Thanks in advance!

PHP CODE:

```
$Type = (isset($_GET['type'])?$_GET['type'] : null);
echo "<b>Type</b>";
echo $Type;
```

Here no value in the type variable is getting displayed.

HTML CODE:

```
<input type = 'radio' name='type' value='Residential' checked<?PHP print   $Type;>> Residential<br>
<input type = "radio" name="type" value="Commercial" <?PHP print $Type;?>> Commercial<br>
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of the form in your post? Also what is `$Type` ?

Comment: please post your form + php code fully

Comment: Are the input fields inside a `<form>` like `<form name="form1" method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >` ?

Comment: Can you share your full code?

Comment: why do you print the type in the input tag?

Comment: Share the complete code please

Comment: https://www.formget.com/php-post-get/ Refer this to understand post and get requests and how they work.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a form with a `method` (whether you want to use `post` or `get`) and an `action`, which will be the URL where to go to, in this case it's the same page (`<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`)

```
<?php
    $Type = (isset($_GET['type'])?$_GET['type'] : null);
    echo "<b>Type</b>";
    echo $Type;
?>

 <form name="form1" method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
        <input type='radio' name='type' value='Residential' checked<?php echo $Type;?>> Residential<br>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="Commercial" <?php echo $Type;?>> Commercial<br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

And you forgot the submit button to submit the form? Or you didn't, but just posted incomplete code. Anyway, above code should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  print_r($_GET);//print values from form
?>
 <form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
    <input type='radio' name='type' value='Residential'> Residential<br>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="Commercial"> Commercial<br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```